# Which programming languages are possible on Blackberry?

Tags: java, javascript, blackberry

I may start porting an android application to blackberry in the next weeks.

I have my problems understanding the RIM documentation of blackberry development.
But I think I understand that I can develop an off line web application. An Application that runs in some kind of WebView but is written completely in JavaScript. Sadly I can't find anything to confirm this hunch.

Has anybody of you build a Blackberry app that loads a local website into a webview? 
Is this possible? Are there any tutorials for this?

Every little pointer to further information is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a "widget" which is an HTML/Javascript application that runs as a native app on the device.  See the BlackBerry Developer Center section on [Web Development](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/) for more information (look for tutorials and videos for "Widgets").